# SVG Icon Path Class in CSS

Tags: css, svg, icons, glyphicons

I'm embedding the following SVG icon as a `path` in my HTML page:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/></svg>
```

How can I include the above SVG icon `path` as a `class` in CSS? So I can just use it as an `attribute` in my HTML page like this:

```
<i class="chevron-right"></i>
```

**Update**: With respect to the accepted answer, I had some problems getting the icon to vertically center properly and ended up finding a much simpler CSS code:

```
.chevron-right {
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use it as background:

```css
.chevron-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/></svg>') 0 0/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<i class="chevron-right"></i>
<i class="chevron-right" style="width:2rem"></i>
<i class="chevron-right" style="width:4rem"></i>
```

In case you want coloration consider mask:

```css
.chevron-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  -webkit-mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/></svg>') 0 0/contain;
  background: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<i class="chevron-right"></i>
<i class="chevron-right" style="width:2rem;color:red;"></i>
<i class="chevron-right" style="width:4rem;color:blue;"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom Element: `<svg-icon path="your d path"></svg-icon>`

```html
<style>
  svg-icon svg {
    width: 80px;
    height:80px;
    background: grey;
  }
</style>

<svg-icon path="M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"></svg-icon>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-icon", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="${this.getAttribute("path")}"/></svg>`;
    }
  });

</script>
```

If you need icons, see my pet-project [IconMeister.github.io](https://iconmeister.github.io)